# How To Provide TypeScript Type Definitions for a Subset of Module Types (Without Breaking Type Inference For The Rest)

Tags: typescript

When I create type definitions for a subset of a third-party javascript library, it seems to break type-inference for the remaining subset (without type definitions). **Is there a way to continue to benefit from type-inference on parts of the library that do not have type definitions, while providing explicit type definitions for other parts**?

I am working with a very large private third-party React javascript library, that does not have TypeScript Type Definitions. TypeScript seems to infer types from this library in a way that, most of the time, is good enough for now. However, in some cases, I need to create the type definitions for the code to compile correctly.